# JQuery Mobile - How to treat form data in second page?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

A friend of mine gave me some base jquery mobile code, hoping I could help him deal with the form, except I'm at first year of Uni and only really know Java, although I've spent the past few days trying to learn Jquery Mobile. My problem with this is I have two html pages, and I don't know what happens to the data once someone clicks the submit button.

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.wixstatic.com/ficons/51b590_0ba7af1a8081cb84ffe6b34fbcf2bb73_fi.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click", "#where", function () {
                $("#input").val("w_a");
                $(":submit").click();
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#museum", function () {
                $("#input").val("Museum");
                $(":submit").click();
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#night", function () {
                $("#input").val("Nightclub");
                $(":submit").click();
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#res", function () {
                $("#input").val("Restaurant");
                $(":submit").click();
            });
            $(document).on("click", "#shop", function () {
                $("#input").val("Shopping");
                $(":submit").click();
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(":submit").click(function (e) {
                    var txt = $.trim($("#input").val());
                    txt = txt.split(" ").join("");
                    $("#input").val(txt);
                    if ($("#input").val() === "") {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-header .ui-title{
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" >
                <h1>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content">
                <form method="post" action="pagetwo.html" data-ajax="false">
                    <input name="search" type="search" id="input" placeholder="Where do you want to go?"/>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                        <li><a id="museum" href="#">Museum</a></li>
                        <li><a id="night" href="#">Nightclub</a></li>
                        <li><a id="res" href="#">Restaurant</a></li>
                        <li><a id="shop" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Radius (km):</p>
                    <input name="distance" type="range" data-highlight="true" id="slider" value="25" min="1" max="25" />
                    <input data-icon="star" type="submit" value="Search">
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" id="where">Where am I?</a>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Rivoli Cinema Hostel</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

pagetwo.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.wixstatic.com/ficons/51b590_0ba7af1a8081cb84ffe6b34fbcf2bb73_fi.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            
        </script>
        <style>
            .ui-header .ui-title{
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header" >
                <h1>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</h1>
            </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" id="custom">
                
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Rivoli Cinema Hostel</h4>
            </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->
        
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the values in the search box and the slider to variables in the second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you need in an easy way, I suggest you use multiple pages in one html (to avoid server side coding - unless you really need that)

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

Working demo with your code in one html: http://jsbin.com/nudoje/7/edit?output

```js
$(function(){
  var doc = $(document),
      one = $('#one'),
      two = $('#two'),
      inp = $('#inp'),
      ran = $('#ran'),
      sub = $("#sub"),
      out = $("#out");

  doc.on("click", "#where", function () {
    inp.val("w_a");
    sub.click();
  });
  doc.on("click", "#museum", function () {
    inp.val("Museum");
    sub.click();
  });
  doc.on("click", "#night", function () {
    inp.val("Nightclub");
    sub.click();
  });
  doc.on("click", "#res", function () {
    inp.val("Restaurant");
    sub.click();
  });
  doc.on("click", "#shop", function () {
    inp.val("Shopping");
    sub.click();
  });
  doc.on("click", "#sub", function () {
    var txt = $("#inp").val();
    out.text(txt + ' ' + ran.val() + 'km');
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-header .ui-title {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.wixstatic.com/ficons/51b590_0ba7af1a8081cb84ffe6b34fbcf2bb73_fi.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="one"><!-- /page1 -->

      <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content">
        <input name="search" type="search" id="inp" placeholder="Where do you want to go?"/>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li><a href="#" id="museum">Museum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="night">Nightclub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="res">Restaurant</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="shop">Shopping</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Radius (km):</p>
        <input name="distance" type="range" data-highlight="true" id="ran" value="25" min="1" max="25" />
        <a href="#two" data-role="button" data-icon="star" id="sub">Search</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" id="where">Where am I?</a>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Rivoli Cinema Hostel</h4>
      </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page1 -->

    <div data-role="page" id="two"><!-- /page2 -->

      <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Rivoli Cinema Hostel Maps</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div data-role="content" id="custom">
        <p id="out"></p><!-- /output -->
        <a href="#one" data-role="button" data-icon="star" id="back">Back</a>
      </div><!-- /content -->

      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Rivoli Cinema Hostel</h4>
      </div><!-- /footer -->

      
    </div><!-- /page2 -->
  </body>
</html>
```